# Nested AngularJS controller misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one controller which is nested into another

```html
<div id="divTest" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    {{test}}
    <div ng-controller="InnerTestCtrl">
        {{innerTest}}
    </div>
</div>
```

When I tried to change a scope value into an inner controller after 3 seconds it was failed. Could you please explain `why` and `how reach` this behavior (I mean that value will be changed, in example from `1` to `2`)?

```js
var app = angular.module("TestApp", []);
app.controller("TestCtrl", function($scope)
               {
                   $scope.test = "a";
               });
app.controller("InnerTestCtrl", function($scope)
               {
                   $scope.innerTest = "1";
                   window.setTimeout(function() 
                                     {
                                         $scope.innerTest = "2";
                                     }, 3000);
               });
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("divTest"), ["TestApp"]);
```

example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/disshishkov/Y3fXG/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `window.setTimeout()`, use `$timeout` service because when you are setting the value of `$scope.innerTest`, it is in the function `window.setTimeout()`, about which angular has no idea at all. When you change the value of the model inside that function the model will not be updated until you call $scope.$apply() function to make the angular know that some value has changed outside the scope of angular. So, there are two fixes.
The first one is:

```
$scope.innerTest = "2";
 $scope.$apply($scope.innerTest);
```

the second one is the best approach, which is actually the angular approach:

```
app.controller("InnerTestCtrl", function($scope, $timeout)
               {
                   $scope.innerTest = "1";
                   $timeout(function() 
                                     {
                                         $scope.innerTest = "2";
                                     }, 3000);
               });
```

Don't forget to inject the `$timeout` service. 
Hope this will make your concept clear about this :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should you [`$scope.$apply()`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-%24scope.%24apply%28%29), or inner service `$timeout`.
I think you need to use `$timeout` service.

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);
app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = 'a';
}]);
app.controller('InnerTestCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.innerTest = '1';
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.innerTest = '2';
    }, 3000);
}]);
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('divTest'), ['TestApp']);
```

or

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);
app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = 'a';
}]);
app.controller('InnerTestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.innerTest = '1';

    setTimeout(function() {
        $scope.apply(function() {
            $scope.innerTest = '2';
        });
    }, 3000);
}]);
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('divTest'), ['TestApp']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should inject $timeout into your controller and use that instead of window.timeout.

Try this instead :

```
var app = angular.module("TestApp", []);
app.controller("TestCtrl", function($scope)
               {
                   $scope.test = "a";
               });
app.controller("InnerTestCtrl", function($scope, $timeout)
               {
                   $scope.innerTest = "1";
                   $timeout(function() 
                                     {
                                         $scope.innerTest = "2";
                                     }, 3000);
               });
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("divTest"), ["TestApp"]);
```